# GAE JSP INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR

Tags: jsp, google-app-engine

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
            throws IOException{
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");

        List<String>result = new ArrayList<String>();
          result.add("Zara");
          result.add("Mahnaz");
          result.add("Ayan");

          PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();

          Iterator it = result.iterator();
          while(it.hasNext()) {
              out.println(it.next());
          }


          req.setAttribute("styles", result);
             RequestDispatcher view = req.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
             try {       
                view.forward(req, resp);

            } catch (ServletException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
}
```

The above is my java class to control the jsp. The below is my jsp file.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="java.util.*"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>JSPTest</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>

<%
  List styles = (List) request.getAttribute("styles");
  Iterator it = styles.iterator();
  while(it.hasNext()) {
    out.print("<br>try: " + it.next());
  }
%>

</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The below is my web.xml

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>JSPTest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.nexwah.JSPTestServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JSPTest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I have tried all I can and still get the error. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GD5S7.png)

I know it would be the mapping problem. But I do not know how to fix it. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rename `index.jsp` to `result.jsp`, and change your servlet to do `RequestDispatcher view = req.getRequestDispatcher("result.jsp");` This is just one solution. Problem is caused by your servlet forwarding to your servlet, which results in an infinite loop.

Comment: As I said, there are multiple possible solutions. The solution I proposed shouldn't require you to change the web.xml.

Comment: Could you explain a little more for me? How is this servlet forwarding servlet  happen? After I changed the name, what is the welcome-file then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Root Cause:**

There is some misconfiguration in several places because of the misconfiguration it happens to be an infinite loop which results in stackoverflow exception.

**How Infinite Looping happens:**

1. ->welcome-file->Forward to url:/index.jsp
2. url:/index.jsp matches url pattern to JSPTest servlet->so servlet is being executed->
3. JSPTest servlet is forwarding request to index.jsp ie.`RequestDispatcher view = req.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");`.
4. view.forward();// which forward to url:/index.jsp.
5. then steps 2 to steps 4 happens over and over again.Hence it makes an infinite loop and causes an stackoverflow exceptions.

**How to fix:**

you need to avoid making infinite loop. So, you can do it in many ways.
You need two different JSP, one for welcome-file and other for servlet forwarded view to break the looping.

**Solution#1:**

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JSPTest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/JSPTest</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This will eventually break the looping.

And you need to call **http://localhost:8080/AppTest/JSPTest.**

And you need to call **http://localhost:8080/AppTest/**.
This will take you to index.jsp page directly without going through to go the servlet.

**Solution#2:**
Keeping `web.xml` same as before, you could use another jsp:`next.jsp` to display. 
That jsp you could configure in 
`RequestDispatcher view = req.getRequestDispatcher("next.jsp");`

Then call **http://localhost:8080/AppTest/**.

Comment: Do you have a solution 2 which I do not need to use the view.forward() method and I only need to create one .jsp file? Thanks

Comment: you need to use view.forward() to `next.jsp`